# Objective-C: Best way to package the contents of a file for Bluetooth transfer?

Tags: objective-c, file, bluetooth, file-transfer

In my program I am sending a file through an RFCOMM connection with a paired bluetooth device. I am having a problem with the receiving end writing the received bytes to a file. However, the receiving end may not be the root of the problem. It may be the way I am loading and sending the data intially in Objective-C. So, *my question here is whether or not my method of loading and transmitting the file's data as bytes across an RFCOMM connection is acceptable.* I am trying to avoid posting a lot of code because it will truly just get in the way. **I would just like to know if it is ok or not to load file data into an array as I have for transferring, or if there is a better way to package the data?**

Thanks in advance.

**Data Types Involved**
IOBluetoothRFCOMMChannel channel
NSData myData

**Load File Code Snippet**

```
// Load file data into byte array.
myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
int bytes[(int)fileSize];
[myData getBytes:bytes length:sizeof(int) * fileSize];
```

**Transmit File Data Code Snippet**

```
// Loops create an int[] chunk array that holds an amount of data from bytes[].
// These chunks (packets) are sent using...
[channel writeSync: chunk length: 1000]; // Sends the packet.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Archives or Serialization methods to convert the bytes streams into an architecture independent bytestream and then send over the RFCOMM channel, and at the receiving end convert it back
[See Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047-SW1)